# Invalid Launch Image. Not Optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: ios8, cocos2d-x, xcode6, iphone-5, launchimage

My Application Loader has asked me to Optimize for iPhone 5. But the fact is...

1. I do have Default-568h@2x.png Launch Image
2. All Screens of my App(Game) does fulfill iPhone 5 ScreenSize Requirements

But still Im getting this error which doesnt make sense. Following are the images from my side
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Following are the Launch Image Names/Sizes i'm Using...

Default-568h@2x (640x1136)

Default-667h@2x (750x1334)

Default-736h@3x (1242x208)

Default (320x480)

Default@2x (640x960)

P.S: My App(game) is portrait only. I'm supporting iPhone 3G to iPhone 6/6+

Comment: Why don't you make sure that all those launch images are filled up. If you don't want to duplicate launch images you can just update the respective `Contents.json` file to point to the right ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asset's name as

- Default.png
- Default@2x.png
- Default@3x.png
- 1x assets for iPhone 2G,3g,3GS.
- 2x assets for iPhone 4,4S,5,5S,5C,6,6S
- 3x assets for iPhone 6 Plus, 6S Plus.